# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0) when using Firebase with ReactJS in Expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to React and Firebase. thank you in advance!

I'm trying to use addDoc from Firebase to create a new document with user input. The function was working fine until I commit my changes in GitHub at which point I get this error when I submit the document.

> WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
> TypeError: window.addEventListener is not a function. (In 'window.addEventListener('storage', this.boundEventHandler)', 'window.addEventListener' is undefined)
> attachListener@http://192.168.1.153:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:152656:32
> _addListener@http://192.168.1.153:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:152670:32
> PersistenceUserManager@http://192.168.1.153:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:148777:36
> @http://192.168.1.153:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:148889:44
> generatorResume@[native code]
> asyncGeneratorStep@http://192.168.1.153:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:21756:26
> _next@http://192.168.1.153:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:21775:29
> tryCallOne@http://192.168.1.153:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:26342:16
> @http://192.168.1.153:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:26423:27
> @http://192.168.1.153:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:27469:26
> _callTimer@http://192.168.1.153:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:27384:17
> _callReactNativeMicrotasksPass@http://192.168.1.153:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:27417:17
> callReactNativeMicrotasks@http://192.168.1.153:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:27581:44
> __callReactNativeMicrotasks@http://192.168.1.153:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:2989:46
> @http://192.168.1.153:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:2789:45
> __guard@http://192.168.1.153:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:2969:15
> flushedQueue@http://192.168.1.153:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:2788:21
> flushedQueue@[native code]
> callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]

Below is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Button,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Dimensions,
    TextInput,
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    ScrollView,
    StatusBar
} from 'react-native';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import { deleteDoc, doc, getDoc, setDoc, getFirestore, collection, addDoc, } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../config/firebase';


export const FinancialProfileScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const Create = () => {
        // MARK: Creating New Doc in Firebase
        // Before that enable Firebase in Firebase Console
        const myDoc = collection(db, "Users")
        const docData = {
            "fname": "",
            "lname": "",
            "uEmail": "",
            "self-employed": isSelected ? "y" : "n",
            "wtwoEmployed": isSelected2 ? "y" : "n",
            "businessOwner": isSelected3 ? "y" : "n",
            "deductionsCredits": isSelected4 ? "y" : "n",
            "capitalAsset": isSelected5 ? "y" : "n",
            "studentLoans": isSelected6 ? "y" : "n",
            "dependents": isSelected7 ? "y" : "n",
            "mortgage": isSelected8 ? "y" : "n",

        }
        addDoc(myDoc, docData)
            // Handling Promises
            .then(function (docRef) {
                localStorage.setItem("currentRef", docRef.id)
            })
            .then(() => navigation.navigate('Sign Up'))

            .catch((error) => {
                // MARK: Failure
                alert(error.message)
            })

    };


    const [isSelected, setSelected] = useState(false);
    const handleSelection = () => {
        setSelected(current => !current);
    }
    const [isSelected2, setSelected2] = useState(false);
    const handleSelection2 = () => {
        setSelected2(current => !current);
    }
    const [isSelected3, setSelected3] = useState(false);
    const handleSelection3 = () => {
        setSelected3(current => !current);
    }
    const [isSelected4, setSelected4] = useState(false);
    const handleSelection4 = () => {
        setSelected4(current => !current);
    }
    const [isSelected5, setSelected5] = useState(false);
    const handleSelection5 = () => {
        setSelected5(current => !current);
    }
    const [isSelected6, setSelected6] = useState(false);
    const handleSelection6 = () => {
        setSelected6(current => !current);
    }
    const [isSelected7, setSelected7] = useState(false);
    const handleSelection7 = () => {
        setSelected7(current => !current);
    }
    const [isSelected8, setSelected8] = useState(false);
    const handleSelection8 = () => {
        setSelected8(current => !current);
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar backgroundColor='#009387' barStyle="light-content" />
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.text_header}>Let's get an idea of your financial profile — <Text style={[styles.subtext_header, { fontSize: 20, fontWeight: '300', }]}> Select all that apply.</Text></Text>
                {/* <View>
                    <Text style={styles.subtext_header}>We’ll provide you with personalized tax & investment tips </Text>
                </View> */}
            </View>

            <View style={styles.subcontainer}>

                <ScrollView style={{ paddingTop: 25, paddingBottom: 15 }}>

                    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>

                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={handleSelection}
                        >
                            <LinearGradient
                                colors={isSelected ? ['#404040', '#404040',] : ['#c1c1c1', '#121212',]}
                                style={[styles.profileCard, { flexWrap: 'wrap' }]}>

                                <View style={{

                                    flexDirection: 'row',
                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                    paddingTop: 15,
                                }}>
                                    {isSelected ?
                                        <AntDesign
                                            name="checkcircleo"
                                            color='#29AA4D'
                                            size={50}
                                        /> :
                                        <FontAwesome
                                            name="user-o"
                                            color='black'
                                            size={50}
                                        />}

                                </View>


                                <Text style={[styles.textSign,]}>

                                    I'm self-employed/ freelancer</Text>
                            </LinearGradient>



                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={handleSelection2}

                        >
                            <LinearGradient
                                colors={isSelected2 ? ['#404040', '#404040',] : ['#c1c1c1', '#121212',]}
                                style={[styles.profileCard, { flexWrap: 'wrap' }]}>
                                <View style={{

                                    flexDirection: 'row',
                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                    paddingTop: 15,
                                }}>
                                    {isSelected2 ?
                                        <AntDesign
                                            name="checkcircleo"
                                            color='#29AA4D'
                                            size={50}


                                        /> :
                                        <FontAwesome
                                            name="institution"
                                            color='black'
                                            size={50}


                                        />}
                                </View>
                                <Text style={styles.textSign}>I'm employed (receive a W-2)</Text>
                            </LinearGradient>



                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    <View

                        style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={handleSelection3}

                        >
                            <LinearGradient
                                colors={isSelected3 ? ['#404040', '#404040',] : ['#c1c1c1', '#121212',]}
                                style={[styles.profileCard, { flexWrap: 'wrap' }]}>
                                <View style={{

                                    flexDirection: 'row',
                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                    paddingTop: 15,
                                }}>
                                    {isSelected3 ?
                                        <AntDesign
                                            name="checkcircleo"
                                            color='#29AA4D'
                                            size={50}


                                        /> :
                                        <AntDesign
                                            name="rocket1"
                                            color='black'
                                            size={50}
                                        />}
                                </View>
                                <Text style={styles.textSign}>I want to grow my small business</Text>
                            </LinearGradient>



                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={handleSelection4}

                        >
                            <LinearGradient
                                colors={isSelected4 ? ['#404040', '#404040',] : ['#c1c1c1', '#121212',]}
                                style={[styles.profileCard, { flexWrap: 'wrap' }]}>
                                <View style={{

                                    flexDirection: 'row',
                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                    paddingTop: 15,
                                }}>
                                    {isSelected4 ?
                                        <AntDesign
                                            name="checkcircleo"
                                            color='#29AA4D'
                                            size={50}


                                        /> :
                                        <Entypo
                                            name="credit"
                                            color='black'
                                            size={50}


                                        />}
                                </View>
                                <Text style={styles.textSign}>I want to maximize deductions and credits</Text>
                            </LinearGradient>



                        </TouchableOpacity>


                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={handleSelection5}

                        >
                            <LinearGradient
                                colors={isSelected5 ? ['#404040', '#404040',] : ['#c1c1c1', '#121212',]}
                                style={[styles.profileCard, { flexWrap: 'wrap' }]}>
                                <View style={{

                                    flexDirection: 'row',
                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                    paddingTop: 15,
                                }}>
                                    {isSelected5 ?
                                        <AntDesign
                                            name="checkcircleo"
                                            color='#29AA4D'
                                            size={50}


                                        /> :
                                        <FontAwesome
                                            name="bitcoin"
                                            color='black'
                                            size={50}


                                        />}
                                </View>
                                <Text style={styles.textSign}>I own stocks, crypto or rental property</Text>
                            </LinearGradient>



                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={handleSelection6}

                        >
                            <LinearGradient
                                colors={isSelected6 ? ['#404040', '#404040',] : ['#c1c1c1', '#121212',]}
                                style={[styles.profileCard, { flexWrap: 'wrap' }]}>
                                <View style={{

                                    flexDirection: 'row',
                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                    paddingTop: 15,
                                }}>
                                    {isSelected6 ?
                                        <AntDesign
                                            name="checkcircleo"
                                            color='#29AA4D'
                                            size={50}


                                        /> :
                                        <Entypo
                                            name="open-book"
                                            color='black'
                                            size={50}


                                        />}
                                </View>
                                <Text style={styles.textSign}>  I have student loans</Text>
                            </LinearGradient>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>

                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={handleSelection7}


                        >
                            <LinearGradient
                                colors={isSelected7 ? ['#404040', '#404040',] : ['#c1c1c1', '#121212',]}
                                style={[styles.profileCard, { flexWrap: 'wrap' }]}>
                                <View style={{

                                    flexDirection: 'row',
                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                    paddingTop: 15,
                                }}>
                                    {isSelected7 ?
                                        <AntDesign
                                            name="checkcircleo"
                                            color='#29AA4D'
                                            size={50}


                                        /> :
                                        <MaterialIcons
                                            name="family-restroom"
                                            color='black'
                                            size={50}


                                        />}
                                </View>
                                <Text style={styles.textSign}>I have children or dependents</Text>
                            </LinearGradient>



                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={handleSelection8}

                        >
                            <LinearGradient
                                colors={isSelected8 ? ['#404040', '#404040',] : ['#c1c1c1', '#121212',]}
                                style={[styles.profileCard, { flexWrap: 'wrap' }]}>
                                <View style={{

                                    flexDirection: 'row',
                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                    paddingTop: 15,
                                }}>
                                    {isSelected8 ?
                                        <AntDesign
                                            name="checkcircleo"
                                            color='#29AA4D'
                                            size={50}


                                        /> :
                                        <MaterialIcons
                                            name="home-work"
                                            color='black'
                                            size={50}



                                        />}
                                </View>
                                <Text style={styles.textSign}>I own a home / pay a mortgage</Text>
                            </LinearGradient>



                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>

                </ScrollView >
                <Animatable.View
                    animation="fadeInRightBig"
                >
                    <View style={styles.button}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={Create} >

                            <LinearGradient
                                colors={['#EA993E', '#CF7C35', '#DF6935', '#D74932', '#D53D31']}
                                style={styles.signIn}
                            >
                                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Continue</Text>
                            </LinearGradient>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>

                </Animatable.View>
            </View >
        </View >
    )
};

export default FinancialProfileScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#121212',
    },
    subcontainer: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#121212',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignContent: "center",
        paddingBottom: 55,
        paddingTop: 5,
    },
    header: {
        marginTop: 50,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        paddingBottom: 5,

    },
    button: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 50,
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    footer: {
        flex: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 3 : 5,
        backgroundColor: '#EBEBEB',
        borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
        borderTopRightRadius: 30,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        paddingVertical: 30
    },
    text_header: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 22,
        textAlign: "center",
        paddingTop: 15,
    },
    subtext_header: {
        fontWeight: '400',
        paddingTop: 5,
        color: "white",
        textAlign: "center",
        fontSize: 18,
    },
    text_footer: {
        color: '#05375a',
        fontSize: 18
    },
    action: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginTop: 10,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: '#f2f2f2',
        paddingBottom: 5
    },
    textInput: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : -12,
        paddingLeft: 10,
        color: '#05375a',
    },
    button: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 15,

    },
    profileCard: {
        // paddingBottom: 50,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        width: 151,
        height: 135,
        borderRadius: 15,
        borderColor: 'transparent',
        borderWidth: 1,
        marginBottom: 25,
        marginHorizontal: 25,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .9)',
        elevation: 5,
        shadowOffset: { width: 3, height: 5 },
        shadowColor: 'rgba(36, 37, 38)',
        shadowOpacity: .3,
    },
    signIn: {
        width: 334,
        borderRadius: 5,
        height: 48,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    textSign: {
        fontSize: 15,
        // fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        paddingTop: 15,
        color: 'white',


    },
    buttonText: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'white',
    },
    textPrivate: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        marginTop: 20
    },
    color_textPrivate: {
        color: 'grey'
    }
});
```

Comment: 1. You need to replace localStorage (which works only on web) with AsyncStorage which works for react-native (https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage)

I didn't post it as an answer since I'm not 100% sure that's the source of the problem

Comment: Also might be good to use react-native-firebase (https://rnfirebase.io/) library instead of just the firebase library.

I got a similar react-native app that uses firebase for authentication if you want to check out how it's configured https://github.com/besnikkorca/swipey.